# Radio buttons as pictures

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, image

I want help in changing the radio buttons into pictures. I know there are other forums with this question but most of them focus on like changing the radio button into an image which also looks like radio button but maybe more stylish. What I am trying to do is when a user registers I want to give him/her 4 pictures and they should chose one of it as their profile picture. When they click on the one of the picture I would like it to highlight like this  -

[image]

I have the following code now

```
<table>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right;">First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="20"></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="20"></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Zipcode:</td><td><input type="text" name="zipcode" maxlength="5"></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Email (used for log in):</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Re-enter Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password_reentry"></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right;">Admin:</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="/avinash/pictures/maleprofilepicture1.jpg" height="40" width="40"></td><td><img src="/avinash/pictures/maleprofilepicture2.jpg" height="40" width="40"></td><td><img src="/avinash/pictures/femaleprofilepicture1.jpg" height="40" width="40"></td><td><img src="/avinash/pictures/femaleprofilepicture2.jpg" height="40" width="40"></td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to change the images at the bottom into radio buttons

Can anyone please help me with how to do this. I don't have much programming experience so any code to start of would be really nice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should really post a picture of your question, makes it so much easier to understand what you're asking ?

Comment: Instead of showing a picture of the question, you should show at least a minimal piece of code.

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery instead?

Comment: @adeneo LMFAO look what you made him do haha. To OP, it's basically listening to `click` events and storing state in a variable. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum lol I actually had the image from before adeneo commented. I wanted to use it show the highlighting part. I haven't tried the click events yet but first I wanted to know how to make the radio button look like the image

Comment: @user2636368 What _have_ you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small piece of HTML: Just radiobuttons and their associated label (`for` attribute refers to the id of the radiobutton):

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radio1" checked/>
<label for="radio1">This is text associated with radio1. It could be a <img src="" alt="picture"/> as well</label>

<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radio2"/>
<label for="radio2">This is text associated with radio2. It could be a <img src="" alt="picture"/> as well</label>
```

Then a small piece of CSS, that hides the radiobutton and applies styling to the label. This way, you can hide the radiobuttons altogether and make two pieces of content clickable and togglable as if they were radiobuttons. The labels could contain text, pictures or have a background image.

```
input {
  display: none;  
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

No Javascript required.

So the trick is:

- Use actual radiobuttons. They have this click-to-toggle behaviour built in.
- Use labels and use the proper `for` attribute. This will cause them to be an extension to the radiobutton. It allows you to hide the actual radiobuttons, while they still keep their behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/qUJJ3/

Answer (score 0):

Try it

http://jsfiddle.net/KwN74/9/

In this demo I am using the jQuery instead. I try to make it the simplest way I can.
If you are not familiar with jQuery yet, you could follow this page

http://jquery.com/download/

Now, you just need add this reference

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Including thousands of lines of code to accomplish this simple task seems silly.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, it is since GolezTrol has pointed it out that could be simplier :). I have upvoted to his awnser instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JS but I would go about it this way (OOP):

I would create an int variable, `picNum`.
If the user selects the first image, say, `picNum = 1`, this will be in the click event.

Fall through a switch statement 1 to 4, if it's 1, then the profile image changes to the first picture, 2: the second etc.

```
switch (picNum)
{
    case 1:
        profilePic = pic1;
    break;
}
```